# Play Framework error on messages file I18N

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, playframework-2.1

I am trying to put the following word on messages file in Play on Eclipse:

```
Alavés=Alavés
```

It always gives me an error. If try this way:

```
Alaves=Alaves
```

It works.How do I deal with the accent?

Comment: Which error do you have? Maybe try 'Alaves=Alavés'? BTW you have UTF-8 encoding for this file?

Comment: Oh, it was it.... I can't use the same string